# Can "ABS Glue" damage the PEI sheet when used frequently?

Tags: abs, warping, delamination, pei

I heard about how people dissolve ABS filament in Acetone, resulting in a glue-like solution which then they rub it on the bed and start printing. Apparently, this helps with warping. But I saw it being used only on glass beds, and the printer I have has a PEI bed, and it's an open-frame printer. So, if anyone has used the "ABS glue" on a PEI bed, did the bed degrade over time?

Comment: ABS releases a lot of VOC's proceed with extreme caution, in a well ventilated room. PLA releases almost no VOC's, and PETG releases a tiny bit so still open the window a little. Acetone vapour is also really bad for you, avoid at all costs, and even if you do vapour smoothing, only do it outside where it is well ventilated. I would avoid this at all costs.

Comment: @F.Ahmed this is not helping answering the question

Comment: @FarO In simple terms it is dangerous and releases toxic fumes, so it's a bad idea. Both ABS and Acetone release toxic vapours

Comment: @F.Ahmed are then going to write in all questions on this website mentioning ABS that VOC are dangerous and so on? good luck, it will take quite some time. Also, the issue with VOC is overblown, it's not nearly dangerous as many people think ( https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/16724/2338 ), so in fact 1) it doesn't make sense to scare people as you are doing and 2) it's still not related to the question asked.

Comment: @FarO "Breathing VOCs can irritate the eyes, nose and throat, can cause difficulty breathing and nausea, and can damage the central nervous system and other organs. Some VOCs can cause cancer." - Lung.org
You are wrong about the VOC levels emitted, it is not as bad as SLA Resin printing but still bad. Videos on YouTube where they have been tested will confirm this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shxid-Z_xo0
ABS also releases carciogenic vapours